# How do I transfer pictures from iPhoto to iCloud Drive?

Tags: macos, icloud, photos.app

I have 17000 pictures in my iPhoto library. How do I transfer them to iCloud Drive?

Comment: What iCloud library are you talking about? iCloud Drive? The as yet unreleased 'Photos' app?

Comment: Apologies, I meant iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Find the location of your iPhoto library (usually in ~/Pictures) and move it to the iCloud Drive folder in Finder. Once the library has moved, you can switch library in iPhoto by launching iPhoto with ⌥, then selecting the new library location.

Comment: So i moved Library to iCloud Drive. How do I retrieve pictures on my iPhone from icloud Drive ?

Comment: @user You can't really yet. Some apps for iOS 8 with iCloud Drive support will allow you to browse the file structure of your library to find the JPEGs, but as for actually 'looking' through your library, that's what the upcoming Photos app is for, scheduled to be released early next year alongside the discontinuation of iPhoto and Aperture.

Answer (score 0):

All your contents inside the iCloud Drive can be accessed from your iphone. Just click on icloud drive in your iphone and you can see everything, including your pictures.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2021, I tried moving my Photo library into iCloud Drive, and I see "Ineligible"

[image]
[image]